# Waiting on events in other requests in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I have a simple Twisted server that handles requests like this (obviously, asynchronously)

```
global SomeSharedMemory
if SomeSharedMemory is None:
    SomeSharedMemory = LoadSharedMemory()
return PickSomething(SomeSharedMemory)
```

Where SomeSharedMemory is loaded from a database.

I want to avoid loading SomeSharedMemory from the database multiple times.  Specifically, when the server first starts, and we get two concurrent incoming requests, we might see something like this:

Request 1: Check for SomeSharedMemory, don't find it
Request 1: Issue database query to load SSM
Request 2: Check for SSM, don't find it
Request 2: Issue database query to load SSM
Request 1: Query returns, store SSM
Request 1: Return result
Request 2: Query returns, store SSM
Request 2: Return result

With more concurrent requests, the database gets hammered.  I'd like to do something like this (see http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects):

```
global SomeSharedMemory, SSMEvent
if SomeSharedMemory is None:
    if not SSMEvent.isSet():
        SSMEvent.wait()
    else:
        # assumes that the event is initialized "set"
        SSMEvent.clear()
        SomeSharedMemory = LoadSharedMemory()
        SSMEvent.set()
return PickSomething(SomeSharedMemory)
```

Such that if one request is loading the shared memory, other requests will wait politely until the query is complete rather than issue their own duplicate database queries.

Is this possible in Twisted?

Comment: When you say `SomeSharedMemory` you're not actually referring to any form of [Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory), are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your example is set up, it's hard to see how you could actually have the problem you're describing.  If a second request comes in to your Twisted server before the call to `LoadSharedMemory` issued by the first has returned, then the second request will just wait before being processed.  When it is finally handled, `SomeSharedMemory` will be initialized and there will be no duplication.

However, I suppose maybe it is the case that `LoadSharedMemory` is asynchronous and returns a `Deferred`, so that your code really looks more like this:

```
def handleRequest(request):
    if SomeSharedMemory is None:
        d = initSharedMemory()
        d.addCallback(lambda ignored: handleRequest(request))
    else:
        d = PickSomething(SomeSharedMemory)
    return d
```

In this case, it's entirely possible that a second request might arrive while `initSharedMemory` is off doing its thing.  Then you would indeed end up with two tasks trying to initialize that state.

The thing to do, of course, is notice this third state that you have.  There is not only **un**-initialized and initializ-**ed**, but also initializ-**ing**.  So represent that state as well.  I'll hide it inside the `initSharedMemory` function to keep the request handler as simpler as it already is:

```
initInProgress = None

def initSharedMemory():
    global initInProgress
    if initInProgress is None:
        initInProgress = _reallyInit()
        def initialized(result):
            global initInProgress, SomeSharedMemory
            initInProgress = None
            SomeSharedMemory = result
        initInProgress.addCallback(initialized)
    d = Deferred()
    initInProgress.chainDeferred(d)
    return d
```

This is a little gross because of the globals everywhere.  Here's a slightly cleaner version:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, succeed

class SharedResource(object):
    def __init__(self, initializer):
        self._initializer = initializer
        self._value = None
        self._state = "UNINITIALIZED"
        self._waiting = []


    def get(self):
        if self._state == "INITIALIZED":
            # Return the already computed value
            return succeed(self._value)

        # Create a Deferred for the caller to wait on
        d = Deferred()
        self._waiting.append(d)

        if self._state == "UNINITIALIZED":
            # Once, run the setup
            self._initializer().addCallback(self._initialized)
            self._state = "INITIALIZING"

        # Initialized or initializing state here
        return d


     def _initialized(self, value):
         # Save the value, transition to the new state, and tell
         # all the previous callers of get what the result is.
         self._value = value
         self._state = "INITIALIZED"
         waiting, self._waiting = self._waiting, None
         for d in waiting:
             d.callback(value)


SomeSharedMemory = SharedResource(initializeSharedMemory)

def handleRequest(request):
    return SomeSharedMemory.get().addCallback(PickSomething)
```

Three states, nice explicit transitions between them, no global state to update (at least if you give SomeSharedMemory some non-global scope), and `handleRequest` doesn't know about any of this, it just asks for a value and then uses it.

Comment: Thanks!  My example assumed that the code I wrote was asynchronous.  As you just demonstrated, it's much more verbose to write these things asynchronously.